# JavaFX FXML Annotation

Tags: java, javafx

is there a way to annotate fields in JavaFX Controller-Classes with @FXML and a String e.g. @FXML("label") instead of using the fieldName for reflection ? (i found nothing on the internet, and in need this, because i want to obfuscate fields, and logically they are no longer called as in the FXML file)

Comment: Then you can't use FXML files. As a side note, I have done quite a bit of a reverse engineering as well as development and imho obfuscation causes more headaches to the developers than the reverse engineers.

Comment: No. The [`javafx.fxml.FXML`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXML.html) annotation does not declare any elements.

Comment: Searched in java fx code and the only thing I can find is that none public fields are set to public when a field conatins the @FXML annotations so I guess there is nothing like that. There are no other annoations in the FXMLLoader. Tho in theory would be easy to add I would guess.

Comment: Yea thanks for the answers, but my question is how to do this by myself... how can i make a own annotation for FXML fields with a String for the field-name, i realize that the "normal" `javafx.fxml.FXML` class has not a String parameter